# My Breakpoint at dataTask line returns nil and it directly jumps to task.resume() without hitting response-error-data lines

Tags: json, swift, xcode, uikit

Although my URL works fine in the browser I get nil on here `let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in` .

This is where I call it:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let selectedCategory = recipes[indexPath.row]
            let destVC = RecipeResultsVC(category: selectedCategory.tag)
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destVC, animated: true)

            case 1:
            let selectedRecipe = similarRecipesArray[indexPath.row]
            print("Selected Recipe ID: \(selectedRecipe.id)")

            fetchRecommendedRecipeInstructions(recipeID: String(selectedRecipe.id))
            // Download and set the full-screen background image
            recipeResultsVC.recipeImage.downloadImage(fromURL: recommendedRecipeInstructions[0].image)
            recipeResultsVC.setBackgroundImage()
                default:
                    break
                }

        func fetchRecommendedRecipeInstructions(recipeID: String) {
        print("Fetching recipe instructions for recipeID: \(recipeID)")
        NetworkManager.shared.getRecommendedRecipeInstructions(recipeID: recipeID) { [weak self] result in
            print("Before guard: \(self)")
            guard let self = self else { return }
            print("After guard: \(self)")
            switch result {
            case .success(let instructions):
                print("Fetched Instructions are : \(instructions)")
                //self.recommendedRecipeInstructions.append(contentsOf: instructions)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching instructions: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my network call :

```
func getRecommendedRecipeInstructions(recipeID: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Instructions, SPError>) -> Void) {
        
        let urlString = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/\(recipeID)/information?apiKey=\(Api.apiKey)"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion(.failure(.invalidQuery))
            return
        }
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error fetching data: \(error)")
                    completion(.failure(.invalidResponse))
                    return
                }
                
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                    completion(.failure(.invalidResponse))
                    return
                }
                
                guard let data = data else {
                    completion(.failure(.invalidData))
                    return
                }
                
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let recipeInstructions = try decoder.decode(Instructions.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(recipeInstructions))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(.invalidData))
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: Did you try and set a breakpoint inside the closure?

Comment: Where should i put exactly?

Comment: Right on the first `if let` inside the `dataTask` completion block.

Comment: Either put breakpoint, or either add `print` and see what's happening in your closure... But is this called `print("Error fetching instructions: \(error.localizedDescription)")`? Which one causes it?

Comment: This is the console print for completion completion ```() -> () 0x00000001003fd384 practice`partial apply forwarder for closure #1 (Swift.Result<practice.Instructions, practice.SPError>) -> () in practice.HomeVC.fetchRecommendedRecipeInstructions(recipeID: Swift.String) -> () at <compiler-generated>```

Comment: Do you understand what we are saying? Put a breakpoint inside the closure, for example on `if let error = error`, and step through the code step by step to see what is happening. Alternatively add a lot of print statements on strategic places to see what is and isn’t executed.

Comment: The naive prints if you don't master breakpoints yet: `guard let data = data else {print("data is nil");completion(.failure(.invalidData)); return}; print("Data is not nil")` etc to know where your code goes. So add the prints for each "test" you might pass or fail. For instance if `decoder.decode` fails you don't even know the real decoding error. You'll go into `.invalidData` only.